# SQL Developer AND OR Statements

Tags: sql, oracle, statements

Got a task at my job to get several fields from different tables into one sheet, using SQL Developer. Im a noob to SQL, however managed to build something. Taking a look at my output learns me that the restrictions I built in do not work. Short description below. Can someone please help me?! In my output I still see values other than 1006 in the ATINN field, values other tham Empty in the BWTAR field.. What am I doing wrong?

1. 5 tables linked together
2. Restriction on Users (DMSTRAATL, etc)
3. Restriction on Productgroup (006*, etc)
4. Restriction on some individual products
5. Restriction on product type (HERB, etc)
6. Restriction on specific data field (All products should have atinn = 1006)
7. Restiction on specific data field (all products should have bwtar = empty)

---

```
SELECT 
    dmssap.mara.matnr, dmssap.mara.mtart, dmssap.mara.matkl, 
    dmssap.mara.ersda, dmssap.mara.ernam, dmssap.mara.bismt, 
    dmssap.marc.werks, dmssap.inob.cuobj, 
    LPAD(INOB.CUOBJ, 18, '0') AS CUOBJ_18, dmssap.ZMM_MATNR_MPO.matnr, dmssap.ZMM_MATNR_MPO.pname, 
    dmssap.ZMM_MATNR_MPO.stat, dmssap.mbew.bwkey, dmssap.mbew.bklas, 
    dmssap.mbew.bwtar, dmssap.mbew.vprsv, dmssap.mbew.bwtty, dmssap.mbew.verpr,
    dmssap.mbew.stprs, dmssap.ZMM_MATNR_MPO.matnr, dmssap.ZMM_MATNR_MPO.pname, 
    dmssap.ZMM_MATNR_MPO.stat, dmssap.ausp.atinn, dmssap.ausp.atwrt
FROM dmssap.mara
LEFT OUTER JOIN dmssap.marc
    ON (dmssap.marc.matnr) = (dmssap.mara.matnr) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dmssap.ZMM_MATNR_MPO
    ON (dmssap.ZMM_MATNR_MPO.matnr) = (dmssap.mara.matnr)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dmssap.mbew
    ON CONCAT(dmssap.mbew.matnr, dmssap.mbew.bwkey) = CONCAT(dmssap.marc.matnr, dmssap.marc.werks)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dmssap.inob
    ON (dmssap.inob.objek) = (dmssap.mara.matnr)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dmssap.ausp
    ON dmssap.ausp.objek = LPAD(INOB.CUOBJ, 18, '0')
WHERE (dmssap.mara.ernam) IN (
    'DMSTRAATL', 'V0342628', 'V0343809', 
    'V0336003', 'V0009830', 'V0309577', 'V0010144'
)
AND (dmssap.mara.matkl) IN (
    '006*', '007120',    '007130',    '007140',    '007170',    
    '007180',    '007210',    '007220',    '007230',    
    '007250',    '007270',    '007280',    '007290',    
    '007300',    '007320',    '007340',    
    '007370',    '007380',    '007400',    '007420'
)
OR (dmssap.mara.matnr) IN (
    '000000010001767697',     '000000010001870117',     '000000010001870116',     '000000010001870115',    
    '000000010001870114',     '000000010001870113',     '000000010001870112'
)
AND (dmssap.mara.mtart) IN ('HERB', 'HALB', 'ZSTP')
AND (dmssap.ausp.atinn) = '1006'
AND (dmssap.mbew.bwtar) IS NULL;
```

Comment: There's an evaluation order: `NOT` -> `AND` -> `OR`, which can be manipulated using brackets `()`.

Answer (score 1):

**AND** operator has an higher precedence order than **OR** . to make your query easily readable use braces () around filter clauses.

Let's say you want to select records which have certain values in dmssap.mara.matkl or certain values in dmssap.mara.matnr then you can use braces between these blocks to be precise as shown below.

```
AND (
(dmssap.mara.matkl) IN (
    '006*', '007120',    '007130',    '007140',    '007170',    
    '007180',    '007210',    '007220',    '007230',    
    '007250',    '007270',    '007280',    '007290',    
    '007300',    '007320',    '007340',    
    '007370',    '007380',    '007400',    '007420'
)
OR (dmssap.mara.matnr) IN (
    '000000010001767697',     '000000010001870117',     '000000010001870116',     '000000010001870115',    
    '000000010001870114',     '000000010001870113',     '000000010001870112'
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (dmssap.mara.ernam) IN (
    'DMSTRAATL', 'V0342628', 'V0343809', 
    'V0336003', 'V0009830', 'V0309577', 'V0010144'
)
AND (dmssap.mara.matkl) IN (
    '006*', '007120',    '007130',    '007140',    '007170',    
    '007180',    '007210',    '007220',    '007230',    
    '007250',    '007270',    '007280',    '007290',    
    '007300',    '007320',    '007340',    
    '007370',    '007380',    '007400',    '007420'
)
OR (dmssap.mara.matnr) IN (
    '000000010001767697',     '000000010001870117',     '000000010001870116',     '000000010001870115',    
    '000000010001870114',     '000000010001870113',     '000000010001870112'
)
AND (dmssap.mara.mtart) IN ('HERB', 'HALB', 'ZSTP')
AND (dmssap.ausp.atinn) = '1006'
AND (dmssap.mbew.bwtar) IS NULL;
```

The crux is in your `WHERE` statement. The evaluation order for keywords in the `WHERE` statement is `NOT` -> `AND` -> `OR`

What you seem to want is this instead:

```
WHERE (dmssap.mara.ernam) IN (
    'DMSTRAATL', 'V0342628', 'V0343809', 
    'V0336003', 'V0009830', 'V0309577', 'V0010144'
)
AND (dmssap.mara.matkl) IN ((
    '006*', '007120',    '007130',    '007140',    '007170',    
    '007180',    '007210',    '007220',    '007230',    
    '007250',    '007270',    '007280',    '007290',    
    '007300',    '007320',    '007340',    
    '007370',    '007380',    '007400',    '007420'
)
OR (dmssap.mara.matnr) IN (
    '000000010001767697',     '000000010001870117',     '000000010001870116',     '000000010001870115',    
    '000000010001870114',     '000000010001870113',     '000000010001870112'
))
AND (dmssap.mara.mtart) IN ('HERB', 'HALB', 'ZSTP')
AND (dmssap.ausp.atinn) = '1006'
AND (dmssap.mbew.bwtar) IS NULL;
```

Notice the two extra brackets around the OR on the AND

Comment: `AND ((`, not `IN ((`.